# Why is liquid mercury conductive if you do not have the lattice periodicity to describe the collective behavior of conducting electrons?

Tags: liquids

We have electric conductivity in metal because the regularity and interaction in a crystal allow for the creation of conduction bands. We should not find these bands in mercury so how could liquid mercury be an conductor?  How can we describe the electrical conductivty of mercury.

Comment: why wouldn't any metal be conductive in its liquid state?

Comment: Indeed, they all are. Regularity is simply not a factor.

Comment: You just can't us Bloch functions since there is no repeating units. That does not mean that there are not widely shared mobile electrons, we just can't give a nice $E$ vs $k$ picture for their energy and momentum.